# Lorentz transformation in "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies"?

Tags: special-relativity

I must be certainly wrong, but there is something I don't understand when reading the paper on "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies" from Albert Einstein.
All the sources I found give the same equations as [here](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/).

I didn't check the original text, but I think a personal error is way more likely than a translation error.

In Chapter 1.3, when deriving the Lorentz transformation from the original assumptions of special relativity, the paper says:

> Since tau is a linear function, it follows from these equations that
>   $$tau=a\left(t-\frac{vx'}{(c^2-v^2)}\right)$$
>   where $a$ is a function $\phi(v)$ at present unknown, and where for brevity it is assumed that at the origin of $k$, $\tau=0$, when $t=0$ [...]

Then the value of $x'$ being $x'=x-vt$, the paper goes on:

> If for x', we substitute its value, we obtain
>   $$\tau = \phi(v)\beta\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$
>   where $\beta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

But if I do the calculus from the first equation of tau whatever I do I find:

$$\tau = \phi(v)\beta^2(t-(v/c^2)*x)$$

I don't understand. Why do I find $\beta^2$ instead of $\beta$?
The calculus looks fairly simple so I don't see where I could have made a mistake.
Can someone point me to the derivation of this calculus?

On my part I did like:

$$\tau=a(t-(vx'/(c^2-v^2)))$$

$$\tau=a(t-(v(x-vt)/(c^2-v^2)))$$

$$\tau=a(t(1+v^2/(c^2-v^2))-(vx/(c^2-v^2)))$$

$$\tau = a\beta^2(t-(v/c^2)x)$$

Comment: Nico, have a look at the answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/204008/).

Comment: That was exactly my problem!!! Thanks for the fast reply! Sorry I don't know how to upvote your reply when written as a comment.

Comment: No probs Nico, my pleasure.